# Issue with a Table Model

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo, model

I've been having a problem with a table model recently and I can't really explain why this happens. I want to select everything from a table and return it in a descending order. But when I try to display it nothing shows up:

Code:

```
<?php

//Will be used at a later date

namespace Blog\Model\Table;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Blog extends TableGateway
{
    public function __construct($adapter)
    {
        parent::__construct('posts', $adapter);
    }

    public function displayPosts()
    {
        $adapter = $this->getAdapter();
        $result = $adapter->query('SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `date_added` DESC');
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

But when I add an `$id` argument it shows the data:

Code:

```
<?php

//Will be used at a later date

namespace Blog\Model\Table;

use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class Blog extends TableGateway
{
    public function __construct($adapter)
    {
        parent::__construct('posts', $adapter);
    }

    public function displayPosts($id = 6)
    {
        $adapter = $this->getAdapter();
        $result = $adapter->query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post_id` = ?', array($id));
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

It's weird that it works with an argument and not without, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You needed to order it by post_id

```
public function displayPosts()
{
    $adapter = $this->getAdapter();
    $result = $adapter->query('SELECT * FROM `posts`')->order(array('post_id' => 'DESC'));

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Database table structure plz

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Statement::order()` Is it because of the PDO driver ? Should I change it to Mysqli ?